# copy and replace columns of specific lines in a file using shell script

Tags: python, bash

**I have multiples files with data arranged like (columns separated by space (indicated here by "-")):**

data
2500-OPQ--1000--UVA--XYZ
2501-LMN--1001--VNZ--OPQ
2502-OPQ---1002-USS--MNO
2503-LMN---1003-PQR--OGD
data

**After an specific line (here e.g. 2502), I want to move the content of column 3 so that the whole column 3 is perfectly aligned and the rest of the file stays as it is (the data on 4th and 5th column may have different number of characters):**

data
2500-OPQ--1000--UVA--XYZ
2501-LMN--1001--VNZ--OPQ
2502-OPQ--1002--USS--MNO
2503-LMN--1003--PQR--OGD
data

**I would like to use either a bash or a python script for this.**

[For more clarity, attached please find a figure showing the files I am working on. Left: Original file. Right: Modified file. After line 2997 (see column 2), column 5 is moved to the left, while the rest stays the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N12kc.png)

Comment: What have you tried? I see no attempt / code in your question?

Comment: I tried using several things in a separate way. e.g. first copying all lines after 2502 in a different document and then delete the space between columns 2 and 3. In the new document I then added one space between columns 3 and 4, and then copied the whole content of the updated document back to the original one. Just using commands like: awk '$1 > 2501' file.dat > file1.dat....Just wondering how to have a more clean script...Unfortunately I am not an expert on these things...started to learn recently

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need :

```
$ awk -F'-*' '{ if ( $1 > 2501 && $1 ~ /[0-9]+/ ) { print $1"-"$2"--"$3"--"$4"--"$5 } else if($1 ~ /[0-9]+/) { print $0}  }' input.txt
```

#### Output :

```
2500-OPQ--1000--UVA--XYZ
2501-LMN--1001--VNZ--OPQ
2502-OPQ--1002--USS--MNO
2503-LMN--1003--PQR--OGD
```

Just for completeness here you have a Python 3 version :

```
import re

input="""
data
2500-OPQ--1000--UVA--XYZ
2501-LMN--1001--VNZ--OPQ
2502-OPQ---1002-USS--MNO
2503-LMN---1003-PQR--OGD
data
"""

for line in input.splitlines() :
    if re.match('[0-9]+',line) :
        fields = re.split(r'-+', line)
        if int(fields[0]) > 2501 :
            print("{}-{}--{}--{}--{}".format(fields[0],fields[1],fields[2],fields[3],fields[4]))
        else :
            print(line)
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply!I tried (after some modifications, "-" means space in my case) but it did not work. The thing is that the 4th and 5th columns may have either 1, 2 or 3 characters. Then they do not align well in the modified file. (My fault, I should have been clearer when posting the question)

Comment: No worries. If you clarify more your question I might be able to help more. In the mean time, If your **-** are spaces, then  you can simply change them on the code.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I have slightly modified my post and have provided an image showing the specific files I am working on with a brief description of the same. I hope it is more clear now. Thanks in the advance!

Comment: Can you paste the original input and desired output on your post instead of an image? That way I can copy paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
awk '{printf "%4s%7d  %-3s %5s%4d %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, substr($0, 28)}' input_file
```

where `input_file` is extracted from your picture and looks like:

```
ATOM   2996  H1  TIP3G 999     -14.190 -28.766  -0.221  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2997  H2  TIP3G 999     -14.390 -29.221  -1.040  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2998  OH2 TIP3G 1000     21.160  21.806  10.603  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2999  H1  TIP3G 1000     21.614  20.972  10.722  0.00  0.00
```

and the output:

```
ATOM   2996  H1  TIP3G 999     -14.190 -28.766  -0.221  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2997  H2  TIP3G 999     -14.390 -29.221  -1.040  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2998  OH2 TIP3G1000      21.160  21.806  10.603  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2999  H1  TIP3G1000      21.614  20.972  10.722  0.00  0.00
```

You can tweak the spacing and/or positioning of the columns by modifying the format string in `printf`.

If you want to specify the lines to process, eg. `all lines after 2502`, you can say something like:

```
awk 'NR<2502 {print; next} {printf "%4s%7d  %-3s %5s%4d %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, substr($0, 28)}' input_file
```

It outputs the lines before 2502 untouched then re-formats the lines 2502 and after, although I'm not sure if such a switching is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/---/,"--")sub(/1002-|1003-/,"&-")}1' file

data
2500-OPQ--1000--UVA--XYZ
2501-LMN--1001--VNZ--OPQ
2502-OPQ--1002--USS--MNO
2503-LMN--1003--PQR--OGD
data
```